# If you are creating a new service, how do you know where to start reading the kafka topic from?

Tags: apache-kafka, distributed-system

I am new to the microservices architecture. I trying to learn from online resources. So my question is hypothetical.

Suppose you have a Person object and any change you make to that object is published to a topic and the subscribers use that to update their data. Suppose there are messages in the topic like this user got one like, so if you subscribe to that, you will update the persons likes count by one.

Now a new service is deployed who has its own local copy of person. Now this service starts reading the queue and sees the person topic has data going back 7 days in which this person has received multiple likes. So how does this service determine where to start reading this topic from? May be this service's copy of data already has many of those likes accounted for in the back up it received.

Comment: That is mostly up to your application to figure out and manage. If you maintain a "local copy of person" you also need to track how up-to-date that copy is (in terms of the Kafka queue), so that you know which updates still need to be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used a [*compacted* topic](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction) of `(person, likes)`, then the latest messages of this topic would always be the most up-to-date "likes" for the given "person"

Over time of more like events, then older "like" counts will be dropped for the same "person", as per the description of log compaction.

In this simple case, it shouldn't matter if you start from earliest or latest as the new events to the topic should always be the latest count, but if you started from the earliest, you would need to delay when you read the count, as the lag might be somewhat high as you read the currently opened log-segment that has not yet been compacted.